# PLSQL Function declaration

Tags: sql, oracle, function, variables, plsql

I want to take in a number and return twice the argument value.
While I would expect it to go along the lines of

> float timestwo(float num){ num*2; return num;}

plsql seems, however, to demand a more obfuscated approach. I thought I had followed the approach that oracle 11g demands, but upon attempting to execute the below code,

```
exec dbms_output.enable(1000000); --boilerplate
set serveroutput on           --boilerplate
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION timestwo (num
IN number)
RETURN number IS
   product number(2) := 0;
BEGIN
   product := (num*2);
   RETURN product;
END;
/
EXECUTE timestwo(5);
show error                       --boilerplate
```

the dbms throws the following error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00221: 'TIMESTWO' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
No errors
```

Clearly the function declaration is incorrect, but does anybody have any idea how to go about correctly implementing this simple code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function is valid, but you're calling it incorrectly. You've defined a function. but you're calling it as a procedure, as the error suggests.

You can either do:

```
select timestwo(5) from dual;
```

Or in SQL*Plus:

```
var result number;
exec :result := timestwo(5);
print result
```

Your function doesn't actually need to have the `product` variable defined; you could simplify slightly as:

```
create or replace function timestwo(num in number)
return number is
begin
    return num*2;
end;
/
```

... which also won't error for larger input numbers (like `10`) which provide a product with more than two digits. Unless that was intentional, of course... *8-)

Comment: I had no idea it was the function call that was at fault! Perhaps had the error said line 11 instead of line 1 it would have been a tad more obvious! Thanks!

Comment: @Duncan - the `create` and `execute` are two seperate statements, and the error is in line 1 of the second statement. `exec` is just a SQL*Plus shorthand which is expanded to `begin timestwo(5); end;`, which mit not be obvious, thought I thout the error showed the full thing. Character 7 of that is the fitst `t` in the function name - that might also have added to the confusion.

Comment: After an error, one can use `list` to see what SQL*Plus sent, with the line numbers that match the line numbers in the error.